# Is the analytic continuation of an even function even?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation, even-and-odd-functions

Suppose we have an even function, $f$, defined on the real line. 
Suppose this function admits an analytic continuation, defined on the whole of $\mathbb{C}$. Does this imply that said analytic continuation is also even?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $F$ is the analytic continuation of $f$ to $\mathbb C$, what can you say about the zeros of $F(z)-F(-z)$?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Whar matters here is that $\mathbb R$ has accumulation points.